# Autoscroll on Mobile device using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, css-transforms

MY current menu for my site is developed to be responsive through Bootstrap.

Currently when one of the sub menus is open and I open another, the initial submenu closes which forces the tab to slide up, so rather than looking at the top of the menu, I am looking at the middle or even the bottom, depending on how far down the screen I was when I clicked to open the second submenu.

Is there a way, Through using CSS, that I can force the screen to follow the submenu back to the top, so that whatever position the screen was in when I opened the menu, it always takes me to the top?

I would prefer CSS to Javascript but Javascript if neccessary.

Comment: please add a code sample to illustrate the problem

Comment: CSS is unlikely to be able to cause the scroll value to change.

Comment: You can't scroll with CSS, only JavaScript and hash links. But maybe you can achieve using `position:fixed` or `position:sticky` on some elements. Here's some documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Normally scroll is done using JavaScript rather than css but you can use '#' like:

`<a href="#top">Back To Top</a>`

and your menu like:

```
<ul id="top"><li>Home</li><li>Contact Us</li></ul>
```

When you click on "Back to Top" link it will move screen to your submenu.